# Calculate div width/height when inside a zoom/scale transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scale

I have a div inside another div with transform scale applied.

I need to get the width of this div after the scale has been applied. The result of .width() is the original width of the element.

Please see this codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMpBMP

**Image of problem:**

[image]

**Hope this is clear enough, thank you. Code below:**

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  background-color: green;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  transform: scale(13.0);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

   var width = $('.inner').width();

   // I expect 130px but it returns 10px
   //
   // I.e. It ignores the zoom/scale
   //      when considering the width
   console.log( width );

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve width/height of a css3 scaled element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834624/retrieve-width-height-of-a-css3-scaled-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getBoundingClientRect()`

```
$(function() {

   var width = $('.inner')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
   // I expect 130px but it returns 10px
   //
   // I.e. It ignores the zoom/scale
   //      when considering the width
   console.log(width.width);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3aezfvup/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need the calculated value. This can be done in CSS.

**Use calc() to calculate the width of a `<div>` element which could be any elements:**

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

I found this about this topic.

[Can i use Calc inside Transform:Scale function in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205885/can-i-use-calc-inside-transformscale-function-in-css)

---

For JS:

[How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to get the width of the inside green box element in JS not css

Answer (score 1):

i achieved your 130 by this

```
var x = document. getElementsByClassName('inner');
var v = x.getBoundingClientRect();
width = v.width;
```